# How to feed visual selection into ex?

Tags: buffers, ex-mode

Is it possible to select the text of a command from a buffer in visual mode and then feed it to ex?

Like so I can modify the text of the command in the buffer and then after I press some keys have it run as the ex command?

Comment: Would the `@` command work for you? You'd have to have `:` in your buffer but you could yank and then do `@"` (or whatever register you yanked to).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First select some text visually. Then yank it (`y`). Then enter ex-mode (`:`). Finally insert the yanked text (`<CTRL-R>0`).